# Breaking up an algorithm into several parts

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

[image]

I would to divide an algorithm I wrote into parts as shown in the attached file

This is what I did so far :

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Selection algorithm}
\label{mpral}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]  
\State initialization 
\State ini = $4$ 
\State init = $0$ 
\Procedure {DriftingPhase}{}
\For{each source $S$}
\State Broadcast IWD\textendash 
\For{each IWD}
\vspace{0.05in}
\State \small{Compute soil ($i$,$j$) = $ (1-\Pisymbol{psy}{114}).Soil ($i$, $j$)-\Pisymbol{psy}{114}\Delta Soil($i$, $j$)$}
\vspace{0.01in}
\State Compute $P_{r}$ = ($i$,$j$) = $\frac{f(soil(i,j))}{\sum\nolimits_{k\notin vc(IWD)}{f(soil(i,k)}}$
\State f (soil(i,j)) = $\frac{1}{soil(i,j)}$
\EndFor
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\Statex
\Procedure{FindingRoute phase}{}
\For{each destination $D$ }
\State MPRset ($D$) = max{$P_{r}$($z$)\textbar\ $z$ $\in$$R$}} 
\State Send IWD\textendash Rep $2$\textendash hop away
\EndFor
\EndProcedure
\Statex
\Procedure{finalPhase}{}
\For{each source $S$ }
\State MPRset ($S$) = max{$P_{r}$($z$)\textbar\ $z$ $\in$$R$}} 
\EndFor
\State MPRRoute= [S] 
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

These are the used packages

```
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

The following minimal example provides `\phase{<desc>}` which sets a `Phase X - <desc>` description within the algorithm. Note that it's usage only works as expected at the top level of indentation. However, I would think this is sufficient in terms of the presentation of one's algorithm.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode,amsmath}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{\text{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\func}[1]{\text{\textsl{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{phase}[algorithm]
\newlength{\phaserulewidth}
\newcommand{\setphaserulewidth}{\setlength{\phaserulewidth}}
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{%
  \vspace{-1.25ex}
  % Top phase rule
  \Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}
  \Statex\strut\refstepcounter{phase}\textit{Phase~\thephase~--~#1}% Phase text
  % Bottom phase rule
  \vspace{-1.25ex}\Statex\leavevmode\llap{\rule{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep}{\phaserulewidth}}\rule{\linewidth}{\phaserulewidth}}
\makeatother

\setphaserulewidth{.7pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Selection algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State initialization
    \State $\var{ini} = 4$
    \State $\var{init} = 0$
    \phase{Drifting phase}
    \Procedure {DriftingPhase}{}
      \For{each source~$S$}
        \State Broadcast IWD--
        \For{each IWD}
          \vspace{0.05in}
          \State Compute $\func{soil}(i,j) = (1-\Pi\psi) \times \func{soil}(i,j)-\Pi\psi \Delta \func{soil}(i,j)$
          \vspace{0.01in}
          \State Compute $P_r = (i,j) = \frac{f(\func{soil}(i,j))}{\sum\nolimits_{k \notin \func{vc}(IWD)}{f(\func{soil}(i,k)}}$
          \State $f(\func{soil}(i,j)) = \frac{1}{\func{soil}(i,j)}$
        \EndFor
      \EndFor
    \EndProcedure
    \phase{FindingRoute phase}
    \Procedure{FindingRoute phase}{}
      \For{each destination $D$ }
        \State $\func{MPRset}(D) = \max\{P_r(z) \cup z \in R\}$
        \State Send IWD-Rep $2$-hop away
      \EndFor
    \EndProcedure
    \phase{Final phase}
    \Procedure{finalPhase}{}
      \For{each source $S$}
        \State $\func{MPRset}(S) = \max\{P_r(z) \cup z \in R\}$ 
      \EndFor
      \State $\var{MPRRoute} = [S]$
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```